# "java.net.SocketException: socket closed" while binding a UDP socket

Tags: java, sockets, udp, udpclient

I am trying to develop a simple UDP connection and am new to this type of programming. What I was trying to develop is an establishment of connection between client and server. First I send a data from client. It will reach the server as it is and it is working fine. Then the server returns the same data to the client after converting it into uppercase, it also reaches the client. But now am getting the "SocketException" each time I press the buttons. I will provide my codes below.

This is the server code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ServerUDP extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

Label l1;
Button b1;
DatagramSocket ds=null;
String st;

public ServerUDP()
{
setLayout(null);
setSize(300,300);
setLocation(50,50);
setTitle("Server Side");
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

b1=new Button("SEND TO CLIENT");
b1.setBounds(30,70,200,30);
add(b1);
b1.addActionListener(this);

l1=new Label();
l1.setBounds(30,110,150,30);
add(l1);

while(true)
{
  conn();
}
}

public void connect()
{
 try
{
  ds=new DatagramSocket();
  InetAddress ip=InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
  byte[] b1=new byte[st.length()];
  b1=st.getBytes();
  DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(b1,st.length(),ip,9999);
  ds.send(dp);
  ds.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("Error 1 = "+e);
}
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
if(ae.getSource()==b1)
{
  st=l1.getText();
  connect();
  l1.setText("");
  if(st.equals("bye"))
  {
    dispose();
  }
}
}

public void conn()
{
try
{
  ds=new DatagramSocket(6666);
  byte[] b1=new byte[1024];
  DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(b1,b1.length);
  ds.receive(dp);
  st=new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());
  l1.setText(st.toUpperCase());
  ds.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("Error 2 = "+e);
}
}

public static void main(String[] ar)
{
ServerUDP c=new ServerUDP();
}
}
```

And this is the client code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClientUDP extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

TextField t1;
Label l1,l2;
Button b1;
DatagramSocket ds=null;
String st;

public ClientUDP()
{
setLayout(null);
setSize(300,300);
setLocation(400,50);
setTitle("Client Side");
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

l2=new Label("Enter Message : ");
l2.setBounds(10,20,100,30);
add(l2);

t1=new TextField();
t1.setBounds(120,20,150,30);
add(t1);

b1=new Button("SEND TO SERVER");
b1.setBounds(70,70,200,30);
add(b1);
b1.addActionListener(this);

l1=new Label();
l1.setBounds(30,110,150,30);
add(l1);

while(true)
{
  connect();
}
}

public void connect()
{
try
{
  ds=new DatagramSocket(9999);
  byte[] b1=new byte[1024];
  DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(b1,b1.length);
  ds.receive(dp);
  st=new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());
  l1.setText(st);
  ds.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("Error 3 = "+e);
}
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
if(ae.getSource()==b1)
{
  st=t1.getText();
  con(st);
  t1.setText("");
  if(st.equals("bye"))
  {
    dispose();
  }
}
}

public void con(String s)
{
try
{
  ds=new DatagramSocket();
  InetAddress ip=InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
  byte[] b1=new byte[s.length()];
  b1=s.getBytes();
  DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(b1,s.length(),ip,6666);
  ds.send(dp);
  ds.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("Error 4 ="+e);
}
}

public static void main(String[] ar)
{
ClientUDP c=new ClientUDP();
}
}
```

How can I solve this exception ?

Comment: You don't need to keep creating and closing `DatagramSockets.` This is half the problem. You only need one for the server and one for the client, and they can exist for the lifetime of the program in each case. You also don't need to bind the client socket to any specific port. The server should reply to the source-address contained in any datagrams it receives.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This exception occurs when the port that you are using is already being used by some application (might be used by your own application in some loop)

check if ports 6666 & 9999 are being used by some other applications.

Comment: Also there is one more problem. Sending and receiving data can be done only once on both server and client sides. What should I do to send and receive data for more than one time.

Comment: This exception occurs when you do anything with a closed socket. The situation you describe throws a `BindException`.